# possible to narrow a generic with typeguard?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, type-inference, typeguards

I'm trying to narrow a generic, where the autocomplete picks up on that it's hitting a typeguard, and thus won't reach that same block of code again. I think the reason is that I'm not constraining the type to the Generic, but im not sure how i would do that, is it even possible? It feels like it should be possible but im unsure. Any help would be appreciated.

```
// Setup
export type Feature<Geometry> = {
  type: 'Feature',
  geometry: Geometry
}

type Geometry = Point | Curve

interface Base {
  type: string
}

interface Point extends Base{
  type: 'Point'
}

interface Curve extends Base {
  type: 'Curve'
}

// Typeguard
function isGeometry<G extends Geometry, U extends G['type']>(geometry: G, disciminator: U): geometry is Extract<G, {type: U}>{
  return geometry.type === disciminator
}


function isFeature<G extends Geometry, U extends G['type']>(feature: Feature<G>, disciminator: U): feature is Feature<Extract<G, {type: U}>> {
  return feature.geometry.type === disciminator
}

function whatGeometry(feature: Feature<Point | Curve>) {
  if(isGeometry(feature.geometry, 'Curve')){
    return feature.geometry;
                   // ^?
  }
  if(isGeometry(feature.geometry, 'Point')){
    return feature.geometry;
                    // ^?
  } // Autocompletes, and knows that we can't have anything else for a geometry, 
  return;
}

function whatFeature(feature: Feature<Point | Curve>) {
    if(isFeature(feature, 'Curve')){
      return feature.geometry;
              // ^?
    }
    if(isFeature(feature, 'Point')) {
      return feature;
              // ^?
    } // Assumes we can have another Feature<Point> even though the upper typeguard should have caught it

    return;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=5.0.4#code/PTAEGUFMBcFcAcBQkAe8D2AnapoE95JQAxSAQzk0gB4BxSdAWxkzwD5QBeUAb0VFwFIALlAByUhVhUxAGn6gA5g2bRWo%20kxZ5EAX0SJ8hUJtWsuoAAroAlgDscAH1ABhaQDdIB%209EiYAZmQAxkQAQmQAzkR8AkYioBFq9op63g5%20gSFWtg6gqL52ACYRoOFRMYKEomLWPmKpiD4ZwURumJ55KAXFpZHRCnHVbZ71%20oggoAAqQoqwZJiFiP6wdkHQNuh2oDYRptp0nd0le2p4sqAAqoeQRccA2mJxYgC6bAAUylqnGueFO0E2Rj2ChYUQXACUok%20Zjw2xKAFEuphgtA6OceINLro2BUqJQttDtAA6OJcTjcP4RAFAuwgzANJYrNYbLY7SSUGi0a63EwqbTnK75G49WgPJ6vN7%20cgc0Ts6Scti-f6A4HQUGXSGgKVSKhwkjS%20XURFqFFo3iYi7Yji4mDSLbajlEwmnElCMkU5U0ukNZardabUAAdwAFhQTqxJQaqLKozRarlnMNIGxwbwFDZ-G8duG8JGdZAnXzTucxEmxODwRUBHi7VrY4WvqwANwKARt9sdtsTAB6AH4FPoBBms7sixGHfKGzCS-HoOXK63QDXMPb687m4vO1uu2A%20wPQBMAIKwNVBJjwAA2MEgEXOZCKoAA1nZ0IGStBQzhA0QgvfHqBQw6e88A-ZI8gvKItSwUAyCUMczlABRlzsFsxl9ZkAxDCg5SoPMZX1fNqFnUBEw8ZNUyrbZMzZWM8PlEsywrSjq1tFc63zKdtBbbdOx7ft20HNthxo-M6KoGccjnCs007ZD2I5biePbPjF10A8wEPCIIlgZgSm-UBfy2QCiHvdAPz8AiOSIySOEgTwtg-dBYEUYNcGDIgEEITBKkgWZ5kKBJgyci8AuMgyyGc4McBsaADHbZDUMQoA)

Comment: Probably related to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384). If you would check the `feature.geometry` after the first `if` where geometry is checked to be `Curve`, you will see that it is `Point` afterwards

Comment: The problem here is that TS doesn't have a type like "`Feature<Point | Curve> & not Feature<Curve>`" to narrow `feature` to if your type guard function returns `false`, so it gives up.  Narrowing in the false branch only happens if your original type is itself a union, an` Feature<Point | Curve>` is not one.  If you refactor to something like [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WGd1Vw) with `Feature<Point> | Feature<Curve>` then it will start working. Does that fully address your question? If so then I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, aha so it basicly boils Down do that narrowing only happends, if my outermost type is an actual union? Thank you @jcalz it addresses my issue. And gives me the expected response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue you're facing is that [user-defined type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) like `isFeature` only let you specify exactly what should happen if they return `true`, which is to narrow the relevant argument's type to the guarded type.  So for a function whose return type is `arg is Type`, we know that for a `true` result, `arg` will be narrowed to something like `typeof arg & Type`, or `Extract<typeof arg, Type>` (using the [`Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union)), depending on what type `arg` has.  Roughly, if `typeof arg` is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) then you get the `Extract`-like behavior; otherwise you get the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)-like behavior.  (I'm saying "like" a lot here because the actual behavior is a bit more subtle and I don't want to digress too much.)

But when the function returns `false`, the compiler has to try to determine what to do by itself.  There are no "one-sided" or "fine-grained" type guard functions as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#15048](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15048) that would let you say `arg is TrueType else FalseType` or the like.  Right now what happens is, if `arg` has a union type, then you get something like `Exclude<typeof arg, Type>`, which actually filters `arg`.  But if `arg` does not have a union type, then you just get `typeof arg`.  TypeScript lacks *negated types* like `not Type`, so there is no type like `typeof arg & not Type` analogous to `typeof arg & Type` that you can narrow to in the `false` case.  (There was an implementation of negated types at [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) but it was never adopted.)  So the best the compiler can do in general is to leave `arg` alone.

---

That leads directly to the behavior you're seeing with `isFeature`.  The input type `Feature<Point | Curve>` is not a union type, so when `isFeature` returns false, there's not much the compiler can do to the type of the input.

If you want to be able to narrow on the `false` branch, you should consider making the input type a union like `Feature<Point> | Feature<Curve>`.  It's more complicated to do this, since your current `isFeature()` would balk at an input of that type.  But you could refactor to allow union inputs, possibly like this:

```
function isFeature<T extends Geometry['type'], U extends T>(
  feature: Feature<Geometry & { type: T }>, disciminator: U
): feature is Feature<Geometry & { type: U }> {
  return feature.geometry.type === disciminator
}

function whatFeature(feature: Feature<Point> | Feature<Curve>) {
  if (isFeature(feature, 'Curve')) {
    return feature.geometry;
           // ^?(parameter) feature: Feature<Curve>
  }
  feature;
  // ^?(parameter) feature: Feature<Point>
  if (isFeature(feature, 'Point')) {
    return feature;
    //     ^?(parameter) feature: Feature<Point>
  }
  return;
}
```

So `feature` is `Feature<Point> | Feature<Curve>`, making it possible for a negative type guard result to narrow it.  And `isFeature()` is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the `type` `T` which allows union inputs.  When it returns `true`, then the compiler narrows the input to just those union members whose geometry type is `U`, and so a `false` result narrows the input to the complement of those members.

That gives you the behavior you want, where `feature` is narrowed to `Feature<Point>` after a negative check for `isFeature(feature, 'Curve')`, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=5.1.3#code/PTAEGUFMBcFcAcBQkAe8D2AnapoE95JQAxSAQzk0gB4BxAPlAF5QBvRUXAyALlAHJSFWFX4AaDqADmkdAFsYmPH1qIAvokT5CoWrIXQlzUAAV0ASwB2OAD6gAwiIBukTVeiRMAMzIBjIgBCZADOROyc2rygwYZWUupu1p4+-qYW1qCoHpYAJsGgQaFskpF8-Gbu-AmI7sl+RI6YLpko2XkFIWEl3GWNLlUaiF6wlr7Q5uiWoObBQpQ0ACotbfl68op4ANr8kfwAumKgAKrLkLn5C-QAFJJe5PN8cyI0awZGAGRsXIR8S2r0hxyM185jkVgoWD4R0QAEo+HdhFRpvknlQ6PoNqBPqxvlETv9ipwqJQpgj5gA6GTrQx4cmRZhMFhA4IgsGWCGYarDUbjSagADuAAsKKjIFcyc9HvdntQKtZGHZRdQ+pB6DDCdMvKArjNReLpVRDvwVfwYerwpxQMSRKSDZBKRiaQBuSSWt2cECgAB6AH4rvAyJgyAZPOqJVQpYiaCr6JINJxw5AXR6wL7-YHgzBQ6BE5H5rL0tBY5xzFqdbM7fqo0a5dBTebXVaYDac3bk5bPW60wGgyHMGG7XmZbXi6B402SS61KBEEA)

Comment: Wow thanks for the detailed response I actually think I understand! Basically we need the Union types cause it allows the compiler to filter to something like `Exclude<typeof arg, T>`, something that it doesn't let us do if we have a non union type, then we just end up with typeof arg. The difference being that the "filter" functionality that I'm looking for doesn't exist for non union types, since we don't have Negated types. The compiler doesn't know what to do so it leaves it alone. Thanks for the super detailed writeup and all the links to relevant sources!